# It is recommended to put the main image below the bio info in your profile?

Tags: website-design, icon

I am not an expert in interface design (**just if you think my question is bad**). I am designing my own web site where I share my work and add some info about myself.

> On the main page: it is recommended to put the image below the main text?
>   Where should I put the image?

I wish I create an elegant and professional design but I am not an expert in interface design.

Am I trying to annoy the user abruptly with the main icon?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When seeing a shape in a plane, the human eye tends to look for a support, an element where that figure is supported. If we analyze those figures with respect to that virtual support, each of them has a different stability.

A horizontal rectangle is a very stable figure because one of its sides represents that support being greater than its own height.

The triangle has two walls that fall laterally reaffirming that virtual support

Unlike the rhombus and the inverted triangle whose support is a point on which all the weight of the shape falls and makes it swing from one side to the other.

The circle is the only one shape that moves infinitely, sideways or turning on itself. This movement gives it its own instability, and makes it one of its main characteristics.

[image: Stability]

From there, the designer can create from these stability guidelines. It does not mean that this good or bad, they are just design decisions.

[image: Design]

Decisions that can modify the shape weight. For example, being the inverted triangle the most unstable figure, having an upper element that rests on one of its sides, it takes strength from its support and its presence in space becomes much more important. The *arrow* shape and its directionality becomes more relevant than the triangle itself.

[image: arrow]

The circle is always in motion and the eye tends to create a support. Except for its size, the smaller the circle, the greater the importance of space and less the sensation of seeking for a support.

Having this as information, the designer can generate their own perceptual guidelines.

A text box on top of a circle creates bigger instability, the circle is the axis on which the text is balanced from one side to the other:

[image: unstable circle]

A text box under a circle may have more or less instability, depending on its width the circle will have more or less space to move.

[image: circle top]

Although it is also possible to stop at least some of the movements of the circle:

[image: Stability II]

Which one of all the options is the one that best fits your design?

- More stable?
- More static?
- More balanced in space?
- More unstable to call more attention?

Comment: stability? I do not understand? what you want to say with stabilily? sorry I am not a expert in this topic , could you explain me? I just want to a website elegant and easy for my  clients

Comment: See the last edit at the answer

Comment: Apparently you understand the question, for your answer has been ticked as the correct one. Could you please edit the question? I have an extremely hard time finding out what the Asker wants, and why your answer is relevant. I understand there's a language barrier here. Thanks!

Comment: @Vincent What do you think now?

Comment: And +1 for 'Gestalt 101' :)

Comment: @Vincent the language is no a problem for me, just I did not understand him  answer

Comment: @simon Unfortunately, your language was a problem for me--I hardly understood your question :)

Comment: @Vincent sorry I will going to try to create a question well for everyone here

Comment: @simon No sorries necessary. We are all here to help and the majority of us here isn't a native English speaker either.

Comment: @simon Vincent is not talking about your language skills, but about your english writing skills that can be improve

Comment: @Danielillo sorry sorry for I dont use formal english I always use to informal english I will going to try to dont use to informal english here